# Is RESTful API functional testing with pytest possible/a good practice?

Tags: python, api, testing, pytest, functional-testing

I am still a novice programmer and I cannot get my head around how to properly test a RESTful API. I already implemented some unit tests that test each endpoint individually, I would like some tests that test several API endpoints calls in sequence in the same test. Would that be a functional test? Is it usually a common practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional test would be a series of actions simulating user actions on your page. As contrary to unit tests, functional tests aren't aware of your code implementation, they just test the actual outcome - you may even create a functional test in a different programming language or testing framework. [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) is the recommended tool for creating functional tests in Python.

So, for example and implying you have a web frontend to your API, a test could be named `test_anonymous_user_cannot_retrieve_data`. You initialize and open a browser on the related page and check that, for example, "Authorization required" header is showing.

Another functional test could be `test_authenticated_user_can_retrieve_data`. Open browser, use a routine that will log in test user with hardcoded credentials, go to the related page and assert there's test data actually presented to the test user.

I suggest buying (even if you can read it online for free) and reading [Obey the Testing Goat!](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/).

Comment: Makes sense! But a series of API requests to different endpoints in the same test would be an integration test then?

Comment: Not exactly, that would be a lousy written unittest. XD. Integration test would be, kind of, *functional test awared of the actual implementation*. So you for example start your server programatically and then call method responsible for serving the tested endpoint and check that it returns correct value and server accepts that value, sort of. P.S. actually, let me correct myself, testing your single endpoint is an integration test as for that to work whole infrastructure has to work correctly.

Comment: "actually, let me correct myself, testing your single endpoint is an integration test as for that to work whole infrastructure has to work correctly" - I actually had this hunch, thanks for confirming! So i guess I should move the single endpoint tests together with the "scenario" (several endpoints tested) tests to the integration tests folder.